# dos date/time calculation

Tags: datetime, date, time, timestamp, dos

I am working on a project that involves converting data into dos date and time. using a hex editor (Hex Workshop) i have looked through the file manually and and found the values I am looking for, however I am unsure how they are calculated. I am told that the int16 value 15430 corresponds to the date 06/02/2010 but i can see no correlation, also the value 15430 corresponds to the time 07:34:12 but i am lost in how it is calculated. any help with these calculations would be very welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the bits in those numbers.

See here for details:
http://www.vsft.com/hal/dostime.htm

Comment: yep just found the answer myself before checking back here, i've been looking for it for a while, cheers for the link

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old but I think the time 07:34:12 corresponds to 15436 (not 15430).